Web scraping restaurant data using Python in Microsoft Visual Studio
I am attempting to scrape some data including
price (in symbols), and type of cuisine (e.g. street).
I have had some success scraping simpler websites, but this one proves to be a bit of a challenge because there are hierarchies as far as I understand it in html coding. I started the code below and got as far as the iterate part, but got lost because the data seems to be nested in a bunch of tags.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests as req
import pandas as pd                                                                                               

url = 'https://guide.michelin.com/en/vn/restaurants/affordable/luxury/mid-range/premium?sort=distinction'         

page = req.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')                                                                    

print(soup)

#Restaurant details
restaurant_name = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'col col-12')                                                                                  

for restaurant in restaurant_name:
    column = restaurant.find('h3', class_ = 'card__menu-content--title pl-text pl-big js-match-height-title')
    name = column.a.text
    print(name)

Can someone provide some input? All the information I need seems to be embedded inside the love icon, but I don't know if I should be drawing it from there:
div class = <"col-md-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3"> ...<div class = love-icon pl-icon js-favorite-restaurant" ...data-dtm-price " " dtm-region = "Ho Chi Minh" ...data-restaurant-name = "Akuna"

I am expecting to get:

The name of all the restaurants on the page
Location
Price in symbols
Type of cuisine


A solution using selenium with python.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://guide.michelin.com/en/vn/restaurants/affordable/luxury/mid-range/premium?sort=distinction")
popup = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='didomi-popup']/div/div/div/span")))
popup.click()
# Wait for the popup and click it..
rest_data = [[resturant.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "card__menu-content--title").text,
      *[i.text for i in resturant.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "card__menu-footer--score")]]
     for resturant in driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "card__menu")]

for item in rest_data:
    print(item)
driver.close()


What's the difference between selenium and BeautifulSoup?

Here's one approach to read all pages and get the desired information per card. I've added comments explaining the different steps.
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup                                                                                     #Use camel case for BeautifulSoup (and download Python using Homebrew if you are just starting out)
import requests
import pandas as pd                                                                                               

# initialize list for `results` per card on page
results = []

# start at page 1
page_number = 1

# initialize `status_code`
status_code = 200

# while loop: exit when `status_code == 404` (page won't exist; done)
while status_code != 404:
    
    # adjust url for each page
    url = ('https://guide.michelin.com/en/vn/restaurants/affordable/luxury/' 
           + f'mid-range/premium/page/{page_number}?sort=distinction')
    
    page = requests.get(url)
    
    # check `status_code`: process if 200 (success), 
    # and exit loop if 404 (page not found)
    status_code = page.status_code
    
    if status_code == 200:
        
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
        
        # get all 20 cards per page
        restaurants = soup.find_all('div', class_='card__menu-content')
        
        # loop through each restaurant
        for restaurant in restaurants:
            
            # get name from the `h3` header field
            name = restaurant.find('h3').text.strip()
            
            # get `city, price, cuisine` from div with 'card__menu-footer--score'
            info = restaurant.find_all('div', class_='card__menu-footer--score')
            
            # price and cuisine are in same text field
            city, price_cuisine = [i.text.strip() for i in info]
            
            # split on middle dot, '·', to separate price and cuisine
            price, cuisine = [i.strip() for i in price_cuisine.split('·')]
            
            # append values to `results`
            results.append([name, city, price, cuisine])
    
        # track progress
        print(f'page {page_number} processed.')
    
    # increment `page_number` to go to next page
    page_number += 1
    
print('done.')

# collect `results` in a `pd.DataFrame`
df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['name', 'city', 'price', 'cuisine'])

Output like:
import numpy as np

df.iloc[np.r_[0:2, -2:0]]

             name                       city price              cuisine
0           Akuna  Ho Chi Minh City, Vietnam  ₫₫₫₫           Innovative
1      Long Trieu  Ho Chi Minh City, Vietnam  ₫₫₫₫            Cantonese
162       Truffle  Ho Chi Minh City, Vietnam  ₫₫₫₫  French Contemporary
163  Å by T.U.N.G  Ho Chi Minh City, Vietnam   ₫₫₫           Innovative


Thanks @ouroboros1, I can follow what you did. I do have a question though. What's the thinking behind figuring out which layer of the hierarchy you want to be pulling from in your code? For instance, instead of 'div', class_ = 'flex-fill' you went with 'div', class_ = 'card__menu-content'. I am looking at different webpages and I can see where the data is located, but I don't know how to go about choosing what to extract to put in the code.
